# Freetype unicode on Windows

Tags: freetype2

I'm using `Freetype 2.5.3` on a portable OpenGL application.

My issue is that i can't get unicode on my Windows machine, while i get them correctly on linux-based systems *(lubuntu, OSX, Android)*

i'm using the famous `arialuni.ttf` (23mb) so i'm pretty sure it contains everything. In fact, i had this *working* in my previous Windows installation (Win7), then re-installed Win7 from another source and now unicode is not working right.

Specifically when i draw a string, then only latin are rendered while unicode are getting skipped. I dug deeper and i found that character codes are not what they should be in `wstring`. For example, i'm using some greek letters in the string like `γ` which i know it should have a [code point](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=947&preview=entity) of `947`.

My engine just iterates the `wstring` characters and drives the above code point to another vector that holds texture coordinates so i can draw the glyph.

The problem is that on my Windows 7 machine, the `wstring` does not give me `947` for a `γ`, but instead it gives me a `179`. In addition, the character of `Ά` returns as 2 characters of `206` code (??) instead of one of `902`.

It's like simple iterating a `wstring`, like:

```
for(size_t c=0,sz=wtext.size();c<sz;c++) {
   uint32_t ch = wtext[c];   // code point
   ...
}
```

This is only happening on my newly installed `Win7`; it worked before on another Win7 system, along with my all linux machines. Now it's broken on this, and also on my XP virtual machine.

I don't use any wide formatting functions on this, just like:

```
wstring wtext = L"blΆh";
```

In addition, i can see my glyphs being rendered correctly in my OpenGL texture, so not a font issue either. My font generator uses the greek range of ~`900-950` code points to collect the glyphs.

I add the code points per language with this:

```
FT_UInt charcode;
FT_ULong character = FT_Get_First_Char(face, &charcode);
do {
   character = FT_Get_Next_Char(face, character, &charcode);
   ...
} while(charcode);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but i fixed it by saving the file as `UTF-8 BOM`, rather `UTF-8` (i had it by default).

Comment: That will fix it for windows and potentially break it for others. The problem is that UTF-8 does not need and should not use a BOM (it breaks ASCII compatibility). But since windows is architectured around UTF-16, that uses a BOM, many windows utilities do not really support UTF-8, but a strange non-standard UTF-8-with-BOM

Comment: Just in case, i compiled the program in windows, linux, osx, ios and android and there was no problem.